# Css overflow text displayed in few lines without word break - without using display: -webkit-box;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some long text that is displayed within a div this div has a fixed width and height. I want the text to be displayed on a few lines (as the div height) and that the sentence words will not break (word prefix in one line and the continue in the next line) furthermore I want to add ellipsis at the end of the last sentence.

[Css overflow text displayed in few lines without word break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726527/css-overflow-text-displayed-in-few-lines-without-word-break)

I have the following solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/vghup5jf/16/
but it doesn't work on Internet explorer and Firefox

```
 display: -webkit-box; 
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
       -webkit-box-orient: vertical ;
```

What is the solution for Internet explorer + firefox too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6873883/1305911

Comment: if you replace 

`display: block !important;
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -moz-box !important;`

by `display: block; ` i think that it will work on IE & Mozilla and Safari too, can you test ?

and you can of course use overflow: scroll; for making a scroll